# Add images to a markdown while the image name contains % symbol

Tags: github, markdown

The name of my imagefile is "01jan%landiscloudy.png"

I'm unable to add it to a markdown file on GitHub because of the percentage sign (while using the regular `<p><img src=""></p>` method. I should've been careful while naming the images, but now I have a big number of images named like that, already uploaded to GitHub.

Please let me know how can I add such an image on markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <img src="01jan%25landiscloudy.png" alt="Land is Cloudy" width="45%">
    <img src="01jan%25clearisonland.png" alt="Another Image" width="45%">
</div>
```

Putting 25 after the `%` symbol works.